# Creating SymbolicLink with PowerShell does not work

Tags: powershell, symlink

I'm running my PowerShell as Admin and I try to create a symbolic link to another directory.
To do so, I want to use the `New-Item` cmdlet as described in the 
[Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/wmf/5.0/feedback_symbolic).

```
New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path C:\Temp -Name TestDir -Value C:\LinkedDir
```

I made sure, all directories (except the symbolic link itself) exist, but still I get this error:

```
New-Item : Type unkonwn Typ. Only "file" and "directory" can be used.
In Line:1 Row:9
+ New-Item <<<<  -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path C:\Temp -Name TestDir -Value C:\LinkedDir
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Item], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

If I use the New-Item cmdlet just like this

```
PS C:\Temp> New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink
```

I can enter the paths manually, so this means, that my PowerShell actually knows the cmdlet.

Does anyone know what the problem is and can help me out?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the syntax of your command, it works for me. What version of PowerShell / Windows are you using?

Comment: "Type unkonwn Typ."? Someone badly failed a saving throw vs. typos. If I specify an unknown type, I get "The type is not a known type for the file system. Only "file","directory" or "symboliclink" can be specified." (PS 5).

Comment: @MarkWragg Windows 7 with PS 2.0 - I guess I'll try updating my PS then

Answer (score 3):

The code above does not work with PowerShell 2.0 .
After Mark Wragg asked which PS version I use, I upgraded to 4.0 and it worked.
So it seems, that some parameters from the `New-Item` cmdlet are not supported in PS 2.0.

Answer (score -2):

`New-Item SymbolicLink` error Workaround:

On my computer, this command does't work:

```
New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path $link_fullpath -Target $Target
```

If `$link` and `$target` are on the same unit, for example, if `$Target= "y:\xxx\myfile1"` and  `$link= "y:\zzz\Myfile2"` (both on `Y:`). If it's not on the same unit, it works.

On the other hand and fortunately, `New-Item` works if I use `-Name` like this:

```
New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -name $name_link -Path $path_link -Target $target
```

Where `$name_link = "Myfile2"` , `$path_link = "y:\zzz"` and `$Target = "y:\xxx\myfile1"`

So, use `-Name` in `New-Item SymbolicLink` if you have the same error.